# How to get a to and fro travelling results for Prolog?

Tags: recursion, prolog, tail-recursion

I have this Prolog problem, and I want to check 3 things.

1. is it possible to travel from a to b and also from b to a
2. is it possible to travel from a to b and also from b to a AND it tells me the route travelling from a to b.
3. same as number 2 and additional information on what mode of transport to use for each travel in the route.

Currently I managed to get this program below for part (1) but as I run, the program comes out 'yes' even if it is a wrong route. Have no idea why.

```
byCar(auckland,hamilton).
byCar(hamilton,raglan).
byCar(valmont,saarbruecken).
byCar(valmont,metz).

byTrain(metz,frankfurt).
byTrain(saarbruecken,frankfurt).
byTrain(metz,paris).
byTrain(saarbruecken,paris).

byPlane(frankfurt,bangkok).
byPlane(frankfurt,singapore).
byPlane(paris,losAngeles).
byPlane(bangkok,auckland).
byPlane(losAngeles,auckland).
```

(1)

```
connect(X,Y):-byCar(X,Y);byCar(Y,X).
connect(X,Y):-byTrain(X,Y);byTrain(Y,X).
connect(X,Y):-byPlane(X,Y);byPlane(Y,X).

travel(X,Y):-travelLoop(X,Y,[]).
travelLoop(X,Y,_):-connect(X,Y).
travelLoop(X,Y,Passed):-connect(X,Thru),
    \+memberchk(Thru,Passed),
    travelLoop(Thru,Y,[Thru|Passed]),X\=Y.
travel(_,_):-write('Wrong travel input, please try again.'),nl.
```

(2)

```
travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byTrain(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Z,W)):-travel(X,Z,go(X,Z)),travel(Z,Y,W).
```

(3)

```
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,car)):-byCar(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,train)):-byTrain(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,plane)):-byPlane(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Z,V,W)):-travel1(X,Z,go(X,Z,V)),travel1(Z,Y,W).
```

P.S. (2) and (3) couldn't think of the to and fro predicates, only managed to get one way. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `connect` predicate forgets the mode of transport. Change it to:

```prolog
connect(X,Y,byCar):-   byCar(X,Y)   ; byCar(Y,X).
connect(X,Y,byTrain):- byTrain(X,Y) ; byTrain(Y,X).
connect(X,Y,byPlane):- byPlane(X,Y) ; byPlane(Y,X).
```

Second, there's inconsistency in your use of `travelLoop`'s path argument:

```prolog
travel(X,Y):-travelLoop(X,Y,[]).            %// -- start empty. Why not [X]?
travelLoop(X,Y,_):-connect(X,Y).            %// (1)
travelLoop(X,Y,Passed):-connect(X,Thru),
    \+memberchk(Thru,Passed),
    travelLoop(Thru,Y,[Thru|Passed]),       %// -- start from [Thru|...].
    X\=Y.                                   %// why here? should be at (1)
```

The second clause of `travel` needs to fire only if the first was unsuccessful. And why is it detached? Both clauses should be one near the other in the file.

```prolog
travel(_,_):-write('Wrong travel input, please try again.'),nl.
%// This says: succeed always, and tell the user it didn't. 
%// Need to join both clauses into one IF: (success -> true; wrong).
```

The success clause for `travelLoop` is missing:

```prolog
travelLoop(X,Y, Path):- X=Y, %// report the Path to user: ... 
                        writeln( ... ).
```

As for the return voyage, isn't it as simple as switching the arguments? So, rename `travelLoop` to `travel_path`, and rewrite your `travel` as

```prolog
travel(X,Y):-   %// the to and fro loop
  travel_path(X,Y,[X]), travel_path(Y,X,[Y]) -> true ; wrong.

wrong:- writeln("Wrong input. Try again."), nl.
```

Comment: Hi there, Will. Thanks for the tutoring, i am still a beginner in prolog, therefore there is a confusion in the clauses. Thanks for correcting me! I will try n run it and see thank you so much!

Comment: Hey will, below i have just shown u the part i have modified can u please help me see it again, what is wrong? apparently, the bottom parts i couldnt do it now :( so sorry for the trouble. @Will

Answer (score 0):

Actually   below is part of my program, we are required to write in a menu form, so this is one part of the menu. I inserted what u have corrected for me, i tried n i think it works, as i figure that any 2 destinations chosen will be have "yes" answer since there is a to and fro loop. But, I think it affects the option (c) and (d). So i am not sure where the contradiction is.

```
choice(3):- write('Select the way: '),nl,nl,
  write('a. Travel by using the same transportation.'),nl,
  write('b. Travel by chaining together car, train, and plane journeys.'),nl,
  write('c. How to travel from one place to another: cities.'),nl,
  write('d. How to travel from one place to another: cities and transportation.'),nl,
  read(Option),nl,nl,
  write('Enter the place start from: '),read(Start),
  write('Enter the place end at: '),read(End),
  option(Option,Start,End),nl,nl.

option(a,A,B):- travelSimple(A,B),nl,write('yes'),nl,nl,menu. 
option(b,A,B):- travel(A,B),nl,write('yes'),nl,nl,menu.
option(c,A,B):- findall(X,travel(A,B,X),List),nl,writelist(List),nl,nl,menu.    
option(d,A,B):- findall(Y,travel1(A,B,Y),List1),nl,writelist(List1),nl,nl,menu.
option(_,_,_):- write('Wrong option input, please try again.'),nl,nl,menu.

travel1(X,Y):-byCar(X,Y).
travel1(Y,X):-byCar(X,Y).
travel2(P,Q):-byTrain(P,Q).
travel2(Q,P):-byTrain(P,Q).
travel3(M,N):-byPlane(M,N).
travel3(N,M):-byPlane(M,N).

travelSimple(X,Y):-byCar(X,Z),travel1(Z,Y);byCar(X,Y).
travelSimple(Y,X):-byCar(X,Z),travel1(Z,Y);byCar(X,Y).
travelSimple(P,Q):-byTrain(P,R),travel2(R,Q);byTrain(P,Q).
travelSimple(Q,P):-byTrain(P,R),travel2(R,Q);byTrain(P,Q).
travelSimple(M,N):-byPlane(M,L),travel3(L,N);byPlane(M,N).
travelSimple(N,M):-byPlane(M,L),travel3(L,N);byPlane(M,N).
travelSimple(_,_):-write('Wrong travel simple input, please try again.'),nl.

connect(X,Y,byCar):-   byCar(X,Y)   ; byCar(Y,X).
connect(X,Y,byTrain):- byTrain(X,Y) ; byTrain(Y,X).
connect(X,Y,byPlane):- byPlane(X,Y) ; byPlane(Y,X).

travel(X,Y):-travelLoop(X,Y,[X]).          
travelLoop(X,Y,_):- connect(X,Y,byCar);
                    connect(X,Y,byTrain);
                    connect(X,Y,byPlane), X\=Y.           
travelLoop(X,Y,Passed):-connect(X,Thru,byCar);
                    connect(X,Thru,byTrain);
                    connect(X,Thru,byPlane);
                    \+memberchk(Thru,Passed),travelLoop([Thru|Passed],Y,Thru). 
travelLoop(X,Y,Path):- X=Y, writeln('Yes')-> true ; wrong.      
travel(X,Y):-travel_Path(X,Y,[X]), 
     travel_Path(Y,X,[Y]) -> true ; wrong. 
wrong:- writeln('Wrong travel input, please try again.'), nl.

travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byTrain(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Z,W)):-travel(X,Z,go(X,Z)),travel(Z,Y,W).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,car)):-byCar(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,train)):-byTrain(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,plane)):-byPlane(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Z,V,W)):-travel1(X,Z,go(X,Z,V)),travel1(Z,Y,W).

writelist([]).
writelist([L|Lt]):-write(L),nl,writelist(Lt).
```

Comment: it's best if you post this as a new question. Mention this question too and include a link to it. :) Also please show what command you run, what is its output and where it's not what you expected. That way we (all the contributors here) will be able to reproduce the problem and see if our changes has corrected it or not (by comparing the output with the expected results). :)

Comment: for one thing, `X\=Y` should be right at the start of the `travelLoop` predicate, not at its end.

Comment: travelLoop(X,Y,Passed) should *replace* travelLoop(X,Y,_); no need to have both clauses. So you end up with just two clauses, `travelLoop(X,Y,Passed):- X\= Y, ...` and `travelLoop(X,Y,Passed):- X=Y, ...`. If there are more problems after you fix this, post the new code as a separate question. :)

Comment: @WillNess, i have already submitted another questions with this title: How to get a to and fro travelling results for Prolog_2. Hope u can continue to assist me. Thanks alot